# Select All checkbox using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to select all checkboxes using knockout. here is my viewmodel

```
function MasterViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.People = ko.observableArray([new Person("Test1", false), new Person("Test2", false)]);
self.selectedAllBox = ko.observable(false);

self.selectedAllBox.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue == true) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (item) {
            item.sel = true;
        });
    } else {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (item) {
            item.sel = false;

        });
    }
});

 }
Person = function (name, sel) {
this.Name = name;
this.sel = sel;
}

ko.applyBindings(new MasterViewModel());
```

Here is my view

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedAllBox" />
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data.People">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td class="center">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: sel" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I cant get it to check all. Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AneL9/79/). Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `sel` property observable inside `Person`:

```
Person = function (name, sel) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.sel = ko.observable(sel);
}
```

And you need to set this observable int the `selectedAllBox.subscribe`:

```
self.selectedAllBox.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue == true) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (item) {
            item.sel(true);
        });
    } else {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.People(), function (item) {
            item.sel(false);

        });
    }
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3fgzp10/).

Comment: I know that i can make it observable but i cant as i get this data from somewhere else

Comment: then you need to create a viewmodel which wraps a person and has observable proeprties. It won't work with the observable properties.

Comment: How can i wrap it? I tried using someObservableArray(self.People) , but doesnt work

Comment: You need to check the Mapping plugin : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: I am now converting to observable but still not working: here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AneL9/88/